# How does Maven dependency work with Multiple Parents?

Tags: java, maven

Looking at the Maven Dependencies with respect to Multiple Parent Ids. If such is the structure of Parent-ids. Note below mentioned all are Maven Projects and each contains its own pom.xml.

```
Parent-1 
  Project_1
  Project_11

Parent-2
  Project_2
  Project_22
```

Scenario 1:
Let us say Project_2 is dependent on Project_1 and Project_11....Then which of the following is true?
1. Add both the dependencies in Parent-2 pom.xml and expect Project_2 to discover sources of Project_1 ? Logic being that Parent-2 is anyways the parent of Project_2 and therefore building Parent-2 would enable all its child to discover the dependencies.

2. Dependency of the Project_2 has to be done at its own level..which means Project_2 pom.xml has to include both Project_1 and Project_11 .

Is there any other way to manage the dependencies?

Comment: having a dependency on a project doesn't make it a parent project.

Comment: @Stultuske yes I am aware of that..my question doesn't infer this logic, does it?

Comment: you are asking about dependencies, but explaining it to be parent projects, so it's a bit vague on which of the two you actually mean. either way, I don't really see a problem. Just add a dependency to projects 1 and 11 in the project2 and parent2 poms, and put the version in the parent pom.

Comment: @Stultuske thanks for the suggestion.. which means you are voting for Option:2 . My understanding of having a Parent Pom was that it facilitates common dependencies..seems that is not true?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Dependencies are included from parent to Child, also between dependencies themselves. They're called transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dependency to `Parent-2`, but then it becomes a dependency of both `Project_2` and `Project_22`. This is probably not what you want. So it it would be better to add the dependencies at the level of `Project_2`.